# Chrome takes up ages to start up, how to debug?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Google Chrome and have a handful of extensions installed (33).

The startup is reallly slow. When I startup, the window appears.. then about half a minute later, the thubnails for the 8 most visited tabs appear, and then the favicons in the bookmarks bar appear.

Only then it becomes usable and easily takes over a minute.

Is there a good way to debug this?

Comment: 33 extensions is a **lot**. That's the reason your startup is slow, no doubt about it.

Comment: Had you tried the obvious step of running with a fresh profile to confirm that it is something about your profile that is the problem and not Chrome itself?

Answer (score 1):

Perform a binary search for the settings and/or extensions that slow down the start-up process.

Suppose you have a set of candidate settings and extensions `S` that could be responsible for the slow down. Follow these steps:

1. Split `S` into two equal parts `S1` and `S2`
2. Disable `S1`, enable `S2`
3. If startup is fast assign `S=S1`, otherwise assign `S=S2`.
4. Go back to step 1 unless you know enough :-)

The number of start-up required will be propertional to the base-2 logarithm of the number of settings or extensions you want to check.

In your case it will take you 5 steps or browser startup tests to pin down the one bad extension.

Answer (score 0):

Disable extensions one at a time until it loads fast, then you know which ones are slowing it down.

Comment: Or, disable *all* of them, and if it's fast, it's one or more of them. Re-enable one by one (faster, since it starts out fast) until you find the culprit(s).

Comment: Yes, that is one slow way, is there any other *better* way?

Comment: @Lazer Yes, see my answer